# install LVM dual boot with Windows

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, lvm

I am trying to install Ubuntu dual boot with windows. I have about 150G free space in may machine and want to install Ubuntu 14.04 there. My machine has this partition structure

```
Partition 1      Primary     Windows System reserved
Partition 2      Primary     
Partition 3      Primary    
Extended         Extended
   Partition 4   Logical
   <free space>
```

I boot up using a USB startup disk and it detects Windows 7 and asks if I want to install Ubuntu alongside it, however if I select this option, Use LVM option is disabled. Is there a way to install Ubuntu with LVM in this setup ?

Thanks

Comment: You can manually set up lvm then launch the installer.  The question is, how do you want it set up?  How do you want to allocate the space?

Comment: how to set it up manually ?

Comment: First you need to decide how you want it laid out.

Comment: i want /boot 400m swap 8g /home 60g and rest / to root

Comment: Then why do you want to use lvm?  The main reason for it is to be able to create snapshots or create new or grow existing logical volumes later on, but this requires that you leave some free space.

Comment: thanks, i am thinking of getting rid of windows altogether sometime in future...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a /boot partition as ext4 with a size of 256-512MB and another partition you want to use for lvm, using for example `gparted`. Then manually set it up for lvm (assuming the partition you want to use for lvm is number 5):

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/sda5
sudo vgcreate myvg /dev/sda5
sudo lvcreate -n swap -L 400m myvg
sudo lvcreate -n home -L 60g myvg
sudo lvcreate -n root -l 100%FREE myvg
```

Now you can run the installer and pick the "something else" option, and select the logical volumes you just created for the use you intended.

Comment: The last command should be `sudo lvcreate -n root -l 100%FREE myvg`. I replaced Captical L with little l. Reference: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM#Installing_Arch_Linux_on_LVM

Comment: @XiaodongQi, Good catch.