# Dual-booting Ubuntu with Windows 7 on UEFI system

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a UEFI system that already has Windows 7 installed.  Windows is installed on the first SATA disk (sda).  I want to install Ubuntu on the second SATA disk (sdb), which is currently empty.

I have a reasonably good understanding of how UEFI booting works.  I envisage that I need to do the following:

- Manually partition the second disk using the "Something else" Installation Type, creating a ~250MB ext2 partition for /boot (sdb1) and the rest of the disk as an LVM PV partition (sdb2).  Then create root and swap LVs.
- Mount the EFI partition on the first disk (sda1) under /boot/efi, so that the installer can put the Ubuntu UEFI loader files alongside the Windows ones.

I am having two problems though.

1. When I try to partition the second disk, I am unable to create an LVM PV partition.  That type isn't listed in the "Use as:" dropdown menu.
2. There doesn't seem to be any way to mount the EFI partition from the first disk (sda1) under /boot/efi.

Has anyone else worked out how to get around these problems?

Thanks.

Comment: I would use gpt and also include an ESP - efi system partition on the second drive, even though grub always installs to drive seen as sda. http://askubuntu.com/questions/470632/install-lvm-dual-boot-with-windows

Answer (score 2):

Personally, when I want to use LVM, I set it up beforehand using other tools -- either command-line programs (`gdisk`, `pvcreate`, `vgcreate`, `lvcreate`, etc.) or a GUI front-end like `system-config-lvm`. The Ubuntu installer will then see the volume group and the logical volumes I've already created and let me use them.

As to the ESP, the Ubuntu installer doesn't let you explicitly set a mount point. If you ensure that it's identified as an "EFI boot partition" (I *think* that's what it calls the ESP), you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Before reading Rod's answer, I decided to try installing Ubuntu and Windows 7 the other way around, that is to say, Ubuntu on the first hard disk, then Windows 7 on the second disk.

After the routine Ubuntu installation (with LVM), the Windows 7 install went without any problems at all.  It behaved correctly in adding its own boot entry to the UEFI without clobbering the existing Ubuntu one, and installed its own boot manager files alongside the Ubuntu ones in the EFI System Partition on the first disk.

UEFI boot entries:

```
# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000
Boot0000* Ubuntu    HD(1,800,100000,55d903f0-7682-45e4-8743-4c50681b2e87)File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,800,100000,55d903f0-7682-45e4-8743-4c50681b2e87)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a................
```

ESP contents:

```
# find /boot/efi -name \*.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
```