# How to Dual Boot Windows 10 (UEFI) with encrypted LVM Kubuntu 16.04 on 2nd HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu, uefi

I currently have Windows 10 (upgraded from Windows 8 originally installed on machine) running on a HP Envy 17 laptop booting in UEFI mode. The laptop comes with a 2nd hard drive bay, and I would like to install Kubuntu 16.04 to the 2nd HDD for use in a dual boot setup. Because of work requirements, the Ubuntu install would need to be fully encrypted LVM.

I have seen other tutorials that involved similar questions, but all of them involved placing some component(s) of the Ubuntu system on the main (Windows) HDD and using the 2nd HDD essentially as the home folder of the Ubuntu installation. I would like the Windows installation to remain on the original drive and the Ubuntu install to be present only on the 2nd drive.

So the final desired setup is:

- Have an isolated Windows 10 install on the 1st (original) hard drive which boots in UEFI mode
- Have an isolated, fully encrypted LVM Kbuntu 16.04 install on the 2nd (new) HDD compatible with the Windows UEFI bootloader
- Have the option to select between Ubuntu and Windows at boot

I appreciate any help you can offer - thank you in advance!

Comment: And grub only installs in UEFI mode to ESP - efi system partition on sda. But best to have gpt partitioning with ESP on second drive and make it fully bootable on its own. And Hp is not particularly UEFI dual boot friendly. Combination of these: http://askubuntu.com/questions/470632/install-lvm-dual-boot-with-windows and: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256244 and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu