# Install Ubuntu as Dual Boot encrypted alongside Windows 10 encrypted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, encryption

I have a machine with a 1TB SSD. 800GB of which are consumed by a bitlocked Windows 10, 200GB are unallocated and thus free space.

My goal is to set up Ubuntu on that 200GB space, fully encrypted.

To achieve this, I first created a 500MB /boot partition (EXT4) in the free space. Afterwards, I created a "physical volume for encryption" using up all the rest of the free space. Inside of this crytpo-wrapper, I created a partition for /root (75GB) and /home (~125GB), both using EXT4.
When clicking install now, it shows a message saying that /boot and /home are too small. When clicking continue anyway, the installation crashes.

What can I do? How does this need to be set up?

Comment: Is this what you are doing? https://askubuntu.com/questions/470632/install-lvm-dual-boot-with-windows

Comment: I would make /boot larger and advise you to maintain your kernels or it will get full (search /boot full here). From what you posted it sounds as if you are manually configuring your encrypted partitions rather than allowing the installer to do the encryption. Usually you use LUKS and then LVM to make partitions, but I really can not tell from what you posted. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot

Comment: @oldfred, Panther: Yes, that is basically it. I've now run into the problem, that I can't start gparted or even a terminal, they just won't show. This is a fairly new machine, Thinkpad T570, so I don't know if it's a driver issue. Also tried using LTS 16.04, but it's even worse there.

Comment: I do not know LVM. But generally you cannot use gparted on LVM, except to make the /boot and container partition for the LVM. And if Windows fast start is on, then NTFS partition will not be shown. If then you force install, it probably erases the Windows install. Also the default LVM install, is a full drive install which erases everything. Or if you want some partitions outside the LVM besides /boot you must use the Something Else option.

Comment: When you say "/root", you mean "root" or "/", right?

Comment: // , It looks like they're saying "/boot", which is a separate location for boot files like the Linux kernel.